{"errors":["no data provided"]} while passing json payload in curl to update secret id in vault using Cloudbees/Jenkins Pipeline
I am trying to update the secret id in vault using curl in jenkins pipeline. I am getting error "{"errors":["no data provided"]}" during the curl call :
Here is the curl command:
pipeline{
    agent { 
        any
    }
    stages {
        stage('vault') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo "Generating the token"
                    def token = sh(script:'''curl -k --location  'url' \
                        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                         -d '{
                            "role_id": "value",
                            "secret_id": "value"
                         }' | jq -r '.auth.client_token'
                         ''', returnStdout: true)
                    echo "$token"
                    echo "updating the secret id in vault"
                    sh """
                    curl --location -v --http1.1 -k 'url' \
                    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                    --header 'X-Vault-Token: ${token}' \
                    --data '{
                        "data": {
                            "role.id":"value",
                            "secret.id":"value"
                        }
                    }'
                    """
                 }
              }
         }
      }
}


Can anyone please help me how to resolve this error?
